# jQuery UI drag-drop large elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Having a problem with jQuery UI draggable / droppable.

Basically, when i drop the item, it doesn't drop at the point where the cursor is.
It seems to drop at maybe the centre of the element I'm dragging, but certainly not the cursor.

Here is the code:

```
$('.project, .milestone, .todoList, .todoListItem').draggable({ 
    revert:'invalid' 
});

$('.dayWrapper').droppable({ 
    tolerance:'pointer', 
    drop: function(event, ui){ 
        var sch_item = ui.draggable.attr('id'); 
        var sch_person = $(this).parent().attr('id'); 
        var sch_date = $(this).attr('id'); 
        addToSchedule(sch_item, sch_person, sch_date) 
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give some html and code that you are using please

Comment: $('.project, .milestone, .todoList, .todoListItem').draggable({
  revert:'invalid'
 });
 
 $('.dayWrapper').droppable({
  tolerance:'pointer',
  drop: function(event, ui){
   var sch_item = ui.draggable.attr('id');
   var sch_person = $(this).parent().attr('id');
   var sch_date = $(this).attr('id');
   addToSchedule(sch_item, sch_person, sch_date)
  }
 });

Comment: You should edit your original question, and add the code above--since there's no formatting in comments...

Comment: I couldn't find any link to edit my original question.

Answer (score 0):

You must be omitting some part of your setup.  Using essentially what you've provided, I can make an example that drops the item exactly where I let go of it.  You seem to be suggesting that after the drop, it "snaps" somewhere else?  As far as I know, unless you have code added to your drop function to do that, it just doesn't do anything.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VV3fF/) for a simple example taken straight from the jQuery UI examples.

Comment: My HTML layout is essentially a bunch of divs that are "droppable" all aligned in a sort of grid formation (like days / hours on a calendar).
If my "draggable" element is larger than a single droppable element, then it doesn't always drop where my mouse cursor is.

Comment: @David, I get that - what I"m saying is that you haven't provided us with enough code to figure out where your problem lies.  It could be in your CSS, or maybe some code you haven't shown that tries to "snap" the divs to a particular hour/day.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you're looking for the same answer suggested here: [JQuery UI : Drop long element at the cursor location instead of the middle of the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229102/jquery-ui-drop-long-element-at-the-cursor-location-instead-of-the-middle-of-th)

Basically use 'tolerance'.