# Jquery Droppable Snap Issue

Tags: jquery

I am running into a challenge where I have a day planner and I have 15 min intervals.  Each 15 minute interval is 15px.  I have a draggable region that its height is based on number of minutes.  So in short, an hour would be 60px tall.  The challenge is that when I drop onto my snap divs, I seem to snap to the div that is in the middle of my draggable object.  I need it to snap to the top left corner instead.

```
$(function() {
    $(".draggable" ).draggable({ 
        snap: ".snap", 
        snapMode: "inner",
        revert: "invalid",
        cursor: "move",
        handle: ".eventtitle"

    });
    $( ".snap" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var $drag = $(ui.draggable)
            var $drop = $(this);
            console.log( $drag.data( "eventid" ) );
            console.log( $drop.data( "timeslot" ) );
        }
    });


});

<style>
.content{
    width:600px;
}

.content .column1{
    width:60%;
    float: left;
}
.content .column2{
    width:40%;
    float: right;
}

.daycontainer{
    width:150px;
    height:600px;
    border:1px solid #003366;

}

.daycontainer .title{
    width:100%;
    background:silver;
    text-align: center; 

}

.daycontainer .timecontainer{
    width:100%;
    line-height: 15px;
    height: 64px;
}

.daycontainer .timecontainer .hour{
    width:15%;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    font-size:14px; 
}

.daycontainer .timecontainer .mincontainer{
    width:85%;
    float: right;
    font-size:12px;
}

.daycontainer .timecontainer .mincontainer .minute{
    width:15%;
    float: left;
    vertical-align:top;
    background:#cdcdcd;
    height: 15px;
}

.daycontainer .timecontainer .mincontainer .snap{
    width:85%;
    float: right;
    border-bottom:1px solid #003366;
    height: 15px;
}

.eventcontainer{
    border:1px solid #003366;
    width: 150px;

}

.eventcontainer .title{
    width:100%;
    background:#8fbc8f;
    text-align: center; 

}

.event{
    width: 106px;
    height: 60px;
    background:#afeeee;
    margin: 2px;

}

.event2{
    width: 106px;
    height: 120px;
    background:#afeeee;
    margin: 2px;

}

.eventtitle{
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    font-size:12px;
    background:#b8860b;
    padding: 3px;
    vertical-align:top;

}
.eventdetail {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```
<div class="content">
<div class="column1">

    <div class="daycontainer">
        <div class="title">Monday</div>

        <div class="timecontainer">
            <div class="hour">8:</div>
            <div class="mincontainer">
                <div class="minute">00</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="8:00">8a</div>
                <div class="minute">15</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="8:15">8b</div>
                <div class="minute">30</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="8:30">8c</div>
                <div class="minute">45</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="8:45">8d</div>
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="timecontainer">
            <div class="hour">9:</div>
            <div class="mincontainer">
                <div class="minute">00</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="9:00">9a</div>
                <div class="minute">15</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="9:15">9b</div>
                <div class="minute">30</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="9:30">9c</div>
                <div class="minute">45</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="9:45">9d</div>
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="timecontainer">
            <div class="hour">10:</div>
            <div class="mincontainer">
                <div class="minute">00</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="10:00">10a</div>
                <div class="minute">15</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="10:15">10b</div>
                <div class="minute">30</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="10:30">10c</div>
                <div class="minute">45</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="10:45">10d</div>
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="timecontainer">
            <div class="hour">11:</div>
            <div class="mincontainer">
                <div class="minute">00</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="11:00">11a</div>
                <div class="minute">15</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="11:15">11b</div>
                <div class="minute">30</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="11:30">11c</div>
                <div class="minute">45</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="11:45">11d</div>
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="timecontainer">
            <div class="hour">12:</div>
            <div class="mincontainer">
                <div class="minute">00</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="12:00">12a</div>
                <div class="minute">15</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="12:15">12b</div>
                <div class="minute">30</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="12:30">12c</div>
                <div class="minute">45</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="12:45">12d</div>
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="timecontainer">
            <div class="hour">1:</div>
            <div class="mincontainer">
                <div class="minute">00</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="1:00">1a</div>
                <div class="minute">15</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="1:15">1b</div>
                <div class="minute">30</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="1:30">1c</div>
                <div class="minute">45</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="1:45">1d</div>
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="timecontainer">
            <div class="hour">2:</div>
            <div class="mincontainer">
                <div class="minute">00</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="2:00">2a</div>
                <div class="minute">15</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="2:15">2b</div>
                <div class="minute">30</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="2:30">2c</div>
                <div class="minute">45</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="2:45">2d</div>
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="timecontainer">
            <div class="hour">3:</div>
            <div class="mincontainer">
                <div class="minute">00</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="3:00">3a</div>
                <div class="minute">15</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="3:15">3b</div>
                <div class="minute">30</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="3:30">3c</div>
                <div class="minute">45</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="3:45">3d</div>
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="timecontainer">
            <div class="hour">4:</div>
            <div class="mincontainer">
                <div class="minute">00</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="4:00">4a</div>
                <div class="minute">15</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="4:15">4b</div>
                <div class="minute">30</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="4:30">4c</div>
                <div class="minute">45</div><div class="snap" data-timeslot="4:45">4d</div>
            </div>
        </div>      

    </div>

</div>
<div class="column2">   

    <div class="eventcontainer">
        <div class="title">Events</div>
        <div class="eventlist snap">
            <div id="draggable" class="event draggable" data-eventid="1234">
                <div class="eventtitle"><img src="../../common_files/images/FillLeftHS.png">&nbsp;Event 1</div>
                <div class="eventdetail">some crap</div>
            </div>
            <div id="draggable2" class="event2 draggable" data-eventid="3456">
                <div class="eventtitle">Event 2</div>
                <div class="eventdetail">look over there</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Zjap/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229102/jquery-ui-drop-long-element-at-the-cursor-location-instead-of-the-middle-of-th

Comment: Yes it was, thank you Charlie.  Now to find out how to prevent overlap.